# UIButton shows default white background with round corners in IOS 6 but no in IOS 7

Tags: ios, ios6, ios7

I need a code that removes this default background, in IOS 7 there isn't a problem since I don't see this  background.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you choose a button of type `UIButtonTypeCustom`, there will be no default background

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

```
UIButton *infoButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
```

Answer (score 0):

In iOS 7 default UIButton is like hyperlink in web page, with transparent background and no boarders. iOS 7 is actually border less now, If you want to have corners and backgrounds like iOS 6 use custom button.     `UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom]` Now you can set background and other things if you want.